# How to best fill wall-plug holes in a concrete wall?

Tags: walls, hole, concrete-block, hole-repair

My landlord took out some monitor they had originally left attached to a wall in my rental apartment, and has now left me with a nice decorative set of wall plug holes. Assume for the sake of discussion the wall plugs themselves are gone (it's more complicate but that's the bottom line). The wall is made of concrete blocks cemented together, *not* drywall. The holes have a diameter of about 5 or 6mm, and a depth of... oh, I guess maybe 2-3.5cm (some holes have a broken-off piece of the plug wedged inside).

I've "filled" holes before, but it has been more of a patching then a filling : When I use a putty knife with some kind of filler material powder, mixed with water and applied - I never get that much material inside the hole, and the mixture kind of caves in, or becomes recessed slightly - try as I might to make several smoothing and get-material-in passes.

I thought about maybe using some kind of syringe-like applicator (which I would need to get); but maybe there's a less half-assed method to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using concrete patch in a tube.

Then you stick it in the hole and squeeze till it comes out.

[image: concrete]

any concrete filler in the tube will do
Home Depot has it, even Walmart has it

[image]

If you live in a place without stores then lets do the true Do it Your Self method

Do you have a straw (drink straw), and bicycle pump ? If yes mix the concrete to milk density. Use pump to suck up some in the straw, now push it in the hole.

Comment: Can you tell me what the material is? The brand name will probably not be available here. Also, is the right-side image related to the tube on the left?

Comment: @einpoklum and concrete patch in the tube will do, any make. No the right side is not related to left, just a demonstration = ignore it

Comment: I don't live in the US, so no Wallmart or Home Depot... I hope I'll manage.

Comment: @einpoklum   Almost any store that has a hardware section should have concrete patch material.  For a couple of small holes you would want a small tube, as shown in top left picture, not a big tube.

Comment: @einpoklum ok, let's try this.  Do you have a straw (drink straw), and bicycle pump ? If yes mix the concrete to milk density. Use pump to suck up some in the straw, now push it in the hole.

Answer (score 0):

For a concrete block wall and holes that are (in Imperial units) 2+ inches wide by 1+ inch deep I would use regular mortar. I suppose you could increase it's stickiness by adding an acrylic admix instead of water (probably half acrylic/ half water).

This can be packed into the holes and left protruding a bit- than as it dries to a point where it is not still so sticky you can scrape it off flush with surface. You can even further finish it as it dries with a sponge and water.

Comment: 5-6 _mm_ is less than 1/4 inch in former British colony units, not 2+ inches.

Comment: hmmm- you are correct- I read both dimensions as cm for some reason- thanks for pointing this out as I (obviously) had a different picture of what was going on here.